# SWT show Progressbar while running time consuming UI task

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

I need to display a progresbar while running long time consuming task.
The problem is that this task must access UI (to read and update), there fore I won't be able to use

```
Display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {...})
```

As there is only one UI thread...

Also there is a complication of returning data from an anonymous class (the runnable...)

Please advise what can be done.

Comment: I'm assuming the long running code is a thread? Then using async exec should be fine. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: it's not a new thread, it's done inside the UI thread as it requires to update UI draw graph

Answer (score 2):

Please **never** run long running tasks on the main thread. That's what other threads are for. **You can still update the GUI from this other thread**. Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell();
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);

    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (label != null && !label.isDisposed())
            {
                final String text = Integer.toString(counter++);
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        if (label != null && !label.isDisposed())
                            label.setText(text);
                    }
                });

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, 100);
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: But the above is not going to work, as instead 'Thread.sleep(1000);' I am doing a task that access UI!!!

Comment: @yuris I access the gui as well. Please explain what exactly you need to do, so that I can come up with an example to show you how...

Comment: first,the 'text' variable should be a value of a control on gui (lets say some other textbox).